# Implementing a function whose representation has a singularity.

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb R}$
Suppose I want to calculate the value of a continuous function $f\colon(a,b) \to \R$, with $a,b\in\R$, where there are functions $g,h\colon (a,b)\to\R$ such that for $x\neq c\in(a,b)$ it holds

$$ f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}.$$

The value $f(c)$ is defined, but $h(x)=g(x)=0$.

My current algorithm looks like this (in pseudocode)

```
function f(x)
   if abs(x-c) < 10^(-16)
      return f_of_c
   else
      return g(x)/h(x)
   end if
end function
```

It this approach correct? If yes, is the number `10^(-16)` (machine precision) always a good choice? If yes, why? If no, what is a better number?

We assume that representations without the singularity do not exist or are very unfavourable.

Answer (score 1):

In general your approach is wrong and the unit round off error $u$ is not a good threshold. In particular, the spacing between floating point numbers is not uniform.

There are certain fundamental questions which you must answer before an implementation can be attempted: Above all what is your accuracy goal $\tau$ in terms of the relative error? What is the condition number of the function $\kappa_f(x)$? Is it even theoretically possible to realize your accuracy goal using double precision floating point arithmetic, i.e. is $\kappa_f(x)u < \tau$? Or can you accept a larger value of $\tau$.

Now in your specific situation it is likely that at least one of your functions $g$ and $h$ suffer from catastrophic cancellation at $x=c$, as is the case for say $g(x) = 1 - \cos(x)$ at $x=0$. It falls to you to obtain an equivalent expression such as $g(x) \approx \frac{1}{2} x^2$ which is both sufficiently accurate and which does not cancel catastrophically when $x$ is close to $c$. Here Taylor expansions can be an invaluable tools and the order obviously depends on your accuracy goal. Sufficiently far away from zero, you can use the original expression. In general, the subtraction $d=a-b$ is safe if $a$ is twice as large as $b$ in absolute value or the other way around.

In short: you need a conditional statement for each function which can cancel badly, and the width of the interval around $c$ where you must use a safe expression depends intimately on your function.